# Fixed width font in Latex

Tags: latex, fonts

I can't figure out how to have every character have the same fixed width in Latex. In this example:

[image: font]

I would like the characters

> {i \in \math

to have the same width as the others.

Answer (score 5):

From the manual page `(auctex) Fontification of math`:

> In order to make math constructs more readable, font-latex displays
>   subscript and superscript parts in a smaller font and raised or lowered
>   respectively.  This fontification feature can be controlled with the
>   variables 'font-latex-fontify-script' and 'font-latex-script-display'.

You can turn this off by customizing the variable`font-latex-fontify-script` to `nil`.